# How do I transform an inequality on $n$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

I have an inequality:

$$ n \ge C\log^k n \times (A\log(n^r\log^l n) + B)$$

I want to turn it into an inquality

$$n > F(A,B,C,k,l,r)$$

that implies the first inequality, while making it $F$ as tight as possible.
How can I do that?

Comment: I am unclear on what you want... Are you looking for a constant, possibly in terms of A, B, C, k, l, and r, such that the first inequality will hold? That is, you are assuming/guessing/know that the inequality is true in a set which includes an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$, and you want to find the smallest such $a$?

Comment: Are you asking for a "simpler" function F greater than the given one? If so, simpler in what way, to comprehend, calculate, or what? Also, in your notation above, does $\log^2{x} = \log{\log x}\ $  or $(\log x)^2$

Comment: $\log^2 x = (\log x)^2$   Note that in the first inequality, there is dependence on $n$ on both sides of the inequality. The constants $A,B,C,k,l,r,s$ are fixed. I am looking for a way to find an inequality of the form $n \ge F(A,B,C,k,l,r,s)$ such that $F$ does not depend on $n$, the dependence on $n$ is only on the left handside. The new inequality should entail the first one.

Comment: (Imagine solving the first inequality with respect to $n$. Then we would get $n >= ...$ like I want. But it is probably impossible to solve it directly for $n$ without using very complicated functions of the constants $A,B,C,..$ etc. So instead I am looking for an inequality on $n$ that would just entail the first inequality.

Comment: Sorry, no $s$. Just $A,B,C,k,l,r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get a satisfying bound on n without iteration.  You can expand the right side to $n \ge AC*log^{(k+r)}n+AC*log^kn*log  log^ln+BClog^kn$.  If n is very large, you can even ignore all but the first term as it will dominate.  Using the fact that $log n$ varies slowly with $n$, start with some guess for $log n$, such as 1 or 2.  Plug it in to the right hand side and calculate a new value of n.  Then calculate $logn$.  Continue to convergence, which should be quick.

Comment: Thank you. It is unfortunate I cannot translate it into an analytic solution.

Comment: If you ignore the later terms, Lambert's W function will provide the answer-see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function under Applications.  Of course, you have to have a way to calculate W...